# Cloud FunctionsでRequestにセットした配列の値が取得できない

Tags: javascript, java, google-cloud

テラテイルにて質問させて頂いておりますが、投稿させてください。
https://teratail.com/questions/120751

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Requestで送信したパラメータから、配列でセットされたデータを取得したい。

開発環境
送信側　Java　Idea
Cloud側　Javascript　　Cloud　Function

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

配列の外の値は取得できて、データストアに登録できている。

配列でセットしたパラメータを、For文で取得処理を行っているが値が取れない。
エラーはキャッチされていない。

#### 試したこと

値をセットした配列の datas をログで表示したが

```
models.dto.functions.GoodPricesDetailDto@96b7b12
```

と表示されるだけで、内容が表示されない。

#### 値を設定しているJava

```
    //配列用の変数を定義
    List<GoodPricesDetailDto> goodsPriceDteailDtoList = new ArrayList<GoodPricesDetailDto>();


    int no = 1;
    for (GoodsPriceItemForm goodsPriceItemForm : goodsPriceForm.getPriceItems()) {

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(goodsPriceItemForm.getPriceItemName())) {

            com.eaio.uuid.UUID priceItemId = new com.eaio.uuid.UUID();

            MGoodsPriceDetails mGoodsPriceDetails = new MGoodsPriceDetails();
            mGoodsPriceDetails.setPriceDetailId(priceItemId.toString());

            mGoodsPriceDetails.setGoodsId(goodsPriceForm.getGoodsId());

            mGoodsPriceDetails.setPriceItemName(goodsPriceItemForm.getPriceItemName());
            mGoodsPriceDetails.setOrderNo(goodsPriceItemForm.getOrderNo());
            mGoodsPriceDetails.setPriceTypeId(goodsPriceItemForm.getPriceTypeId());
            mGoodsPriceDetails.setUnitPrice(Double.parseDouble(goodsPriceItemForm.getUnitPrice()));
            mGoodsPriceDetails.setOrderNo(no);
            mGoodsPriceDetails.save();

            //ここから　配列をセットしている
            //Cloud Function の準備 
            GoodPricesDetailDto goodPricesDetailDto = new GoodPricesDetailDto();
            goodPricesDetailDto.setGoodsId(mGoodsPriceDetails.getGoodsId().toString());
            goodPricesDetailDto.setActionType(actionTypeFlg);
            goodPricesDetailDto.setOrderNo(mGoodsPriceDetails.getOrderNo().toString());
            goodPricesDetailDto.setPriceTypeId(mGoodsPriceDetails.getPriceDetailId());
            goodPricesDetailDto.setPriceItemName(mGoodsPriceDetails.getPriceItemName());
            goodPricesDetailDto.setUnitPrice(String.valueOf(mGoodsPriceDetails.getUnitPrice()));
            //goodPricesDetailDto.setCreatedAd(DateUtils.toString(mGoodsPriceDetails.getCreatedAt(), Const.DB_DATE_FULL_FORMAT));
            goodPricesDetailDto.setCreatedAd(mGoodsPriceDetails.getCreatedAt().toString());

            goodsPriceDteailDtoList.add(goodPricesDetailDto);
            //ここまで
        }
        no++;
    }


    // Cloud Functionへ
    GoodsPriceDto goodsPriceDto = new GoodsPriceDto();

    goodsPriceDto.setGoodsId(goodsPriceForm.getGoodsId().toString());
    goodsPriceDto.setManagementsFree(String.valueOf(mGoodsPrices.getManagementFee()));
    goodsPriceDto.setActionType(actionTypeFlg);
    goodsPriceDto.setUserId(userId.toString());
    goodsPriceDto.setPrice(String.valueOf(mGoodsPrices.getPrice()));
    goodsPriceDto.setPaidPayment(String.valueOf(mGoodsPrices.getPaidPayment()));
    goodsPriceDto.setManagementsFree(String.valueOf(mGoodsPrices.getManagementFee()));
    goodsPriceDto.setCreatedAd(mGoodsPrices.getCreatedAt().toString());

　　　//値をセットした配列を代入する
    goodsPriceDto.setDatas(goodsPriceDteailDtoList);

    String firebaseUrl = ConfigFactory.load().getString("url");

    Map map = BeanUtils.describe(goodsPriceDto);

    ClientCloudFunctions cloudFunctions = new ClientCloudFunctions();
    cloudFunctions.execute(firebaseUrl, map);

    Ebean.commitTransaction();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Ebean.rollbackTransaction();
} finally {
    Ebean.endTransaction();
}
```

#### 値を取得する Cloud Function側のJSスクリプト

```
    // GET パラメーター
    if (req.method == 'POST') {

        // DBに接続
        // キーを設定
        // DBに保存する内容を作成する
        const prices = {
            key: datastore.key(['goodsPrices', priceId]),
            data: {
                goods_id: req.body.goodsId,
                action_type: req.body.actionType,
                user_id: req.body.userId,
                price: req.body.price,
                minimum_price: req.body.minimumPrice,
                paid_payment: req.body.paidPayment,
                managements_free: req.body.managementsFree,
                created_ad: req.body.createdAd
            }
        };

        // データベースへ保存
        datastore.upsert(prices)
            .catch(() => res.status(400).send('goodsPrices upsert err')
            );

        for (item in req.body.datas) {
          console.log(req.body.datas)


          // DBに保存する内容を作成する
            const priceDetails = {
                key: datastore.key(['goodsPriceDetails', uuid()]),
                data: {

                // ここから　値の取得ができない
                    bk_goods_prices_id: priceId,
                    goods_id: req.body.datas[item].goodsId,
                    action_type: req.body.datas[item].actionType,
                    order_no: req.body.datas[item].orderNo,
                    price_type_id: req.body.datas[item].priceTypeId,
                    price_item_name: req.body.datas[item].priceItemName,
                    unit_price: req.body.datas[item].unitPrice,
                    created_ad: req.body.datas[item].createdAd
                // ここまで

                }
            };

            // データベースへ保存
            datastore.upsert(priceDetails)
                .catch(() => {
                    res.status(400).send('goodsPrices upsert err');
                });
        }
        res.status(200).send('Success: entryed');

    } else {
        res.status(400).send('No message defined!');
    }
};
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/120751

Comment: ご指摘の件、申し訳ありません。teratailでマルチポストの件の投稿を確認し文頭でお断りを入れましたがstack overflowでのマナーに添えなかった事、お詫びします。もしよろしかったら、こういった場合の投稿方法をご教授くださったら幸いです。厳しいご指摘でしたが、始めてこの質問にコメントを付けて頂きありがとうございました。

Comment: ご丁寧にすみません。ご質問にURLをお書き頂いていてそれで十分です。SOでの扱いは→のmetaをご覧ください。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/

Comment: ありがとうございます、確認させていただきます。